# YouTube likes and dislikes data imported in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, youtube-api, google-sheets-formula

I have a YouTube channel on which I have regular video updates. Now I want to know how many likes are taken on any video and I want to reflect real-time like value to be reflected in Google Sheets also.

So I want some way to link YouTube API to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

### LIKES:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))
```

### DISLIKES:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-dislike-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-dislike-button')])[1]"))
```

Comment: But how can i modify the formula where in separate column i Write the video ID which automatic copy in the formula and accordingly to give result for like and dislike and it should auto refresh also

Comment: if your ID is in A1 then: `=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="&A1,"(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="&A1,"(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))`

Comment: can you help me getting the like/dislike data from facebook also in google sheets.